# Server rendering syntax for react-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, koa, react-dom

Using the server rendering examples for `react-dom` causes syntax errors related to JSX:

```
renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />;
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I am trying to use this in my Koa application but can't figure how to get Node to support it. Do the examples around the web assume that the code is processed with Babel?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: yes.

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't seen anything that's made this explicit. Disappointing that I have to refactor.

Comment: JSX has always required transpilation though.

Comment: Used to that from client development but I was under the impression there was an alternative for server. The examples she been too implicit. Thanks for the help!